# calling python module dynamically using exec

Tags: python

I have 2 modules

mexec1.py

```
def exec1func():
    print 'exec1'
    exec 'c:/python27/exec2.py'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exec1func()
```

exec2.py

```
def exec2func(parm=''):
    print 'exec2 parm',parm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exec2func(parm='')
```

From exec1.py I want to call exec2func of the exec2.py using only exec or execfile...I don't want subprocess.Popen..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `import` instead:

```
def exec1func():
    from exec2 import exec2func
    exec2func()
```

If you want to import using the full path, use `imp.load_source`:

```
import imp

def exec1func():
    exec2 = imp.load_source('exec2', 'c:/python27/exec2.py')
    exec2.exec2func()
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to make it a module and import it. If you need dynamic imports use importlib.

```
mod = importlib.import_module("exec2", package=None)
mod.exec2func()
```

Comment: @nneonneo That method does not deal with packages. But for a base module it would work.